# Sound Not Working - Possibly Sound Driver?

Tags: sound

I was sick of my windows xp computer, so I upgraded to Ubuntu. I know NOTHING about Ubuntu, I have been with windows all my life. For some reason, my sound is not working... I have never heard sound come from the new Ubuntu OS on my PC. I think it may be the sound driver. How do I update my sound card driver? OR get my sound to work? I can provide as much information as you need, please help. Thanks!

**UPDATE** Ok I tried your method, and it gives me this :(

```
root@Garlotch-Linux:/home/garlotch# sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers- 'uname -r' alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'linux-headers' can't be removed
E: Unable to locate package uname -r
```

Comment: It gave you an error message because you replaced [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick#Use_in_programming) with apostrophes. A less confusing alternative would be `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, that's right, there is no space in between. But I am not sure what the answerer expects by just installing these packages.

Comment: We don't have enough information about your computer and installation (e.g. version of Ubuntu). I suggest you you try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems#Things_to_specify_in_your_bug_report

Answer (score 0):

Install the sound card drivers and needed package:

1). Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T.

2). Copy and Paste the following command in the terminal prompt.

3). Press Enter.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

Then reboot.

Comment: i think it might be working so far! :D

Comment: @Garlotch: Please accept this as the answer if this solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: @user308564 NOPE it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user308564 You have zero information. Why are you suggesting to install these packages? `alsa-tools-gui` & `alsamixergui` - Description: GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware & Description: graphical soundcard mixer for ALSA soundcard driver. Will you provide further instructions how to use these tools for troubleshooting? `alsa-source` - Description: ALSA driver sources. Are going to do something with this like modifying and compiling? `alsa-oss` - Description: ALSA wrapper for OSS applications. Did the OP mention a problem with OSS applications?

Comment: @LiveWireBT Sorry. I have answered with my little knowledge. Thanks for pointout the faults. It is much better if you have answered the question.

Comment: @user308564 I also don't have a definite answer to this issue, just the link to troubleshooting on the wiki. :(

Answer (score 0):

Could be a very simple fix. Have you gone into your pulseaudio sound settings? This answer gives a quick overview of basic pulseaudio troubleshooting: https://askubuntu.com/a/505764/311489