# Cannot get my computer sound to work - please help

Tags: sound

I cannot get the sound to work on my Ubuntu computer! I am running OS version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is the think to my alsa information.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a326f05cb4efcf9d8a65535609bea26fbceb2146

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information. Assuming you're using the desktop, have you tried right-clicking on the little speaker icon in the system tray and selecting 'Sound Settings'? You can do a lot of basic troubleshooting in this area. Looks like you have pulseaudio installed, which should simplify things. From this window, under the 'output' tab, you should see a list of your soundcards. You can click the 'test' button on each to generate some audio.

Make sure, of course, that you have your speakers plugged into the right card! You have multiple cards in your machine, and if pulseaudio is choosing one you don't use by default, that could be the whole problem right there. You may want to research your make and model of pc to see which sound card corresponds to which audio output jack.

Another way to troubleshoot is to get some audio playing in an application, then open your unity dash and type pavucontrol. Launch the PulseAudio Volume Control application. Under the 'playback' tab, you should see a list of software audio sources. Find the one playing your audio, and the output meter should be moving. It will display the sound card being used, and you can click on this button select from your different sound cards. Make sure, again, that any sound card you're choosing actually has the speakers plugged into it.

Good luck!